# Set "zero" value to member variable

Tags: c++, oop, class, constructor, member-variables

I'm having trouble understanding some C++ concepts.

When is it appropriate to use a member pointer vs a member variable?

Let's say I have a tree structure and thus a `Node` class. My intuition would be to use a variable for its `Data` and `Edge` (because the `Node` "owns" the `Data`) and a pointer to the parent `Node`. Is this correct?

```
class Node {
public:
    Data data;
    Edge edge;
    Node *parent;
}
```

When I implement a custom creator method for the `Node` class, I also have to initialize the member variables (but not the pointers?). For the root `Node` I can set the parent pointer to `NULL`.

But what do I do with the `Edge` variable? The root `Node` has no parent and no `Edge` leading to it from its parent. Can I somehow set it to a "zero" value? If it matters, the `Edge` class has no default constructor, but something like this: `Edge(int length, int width)`.

Comment: What does the `Edge` represent? How is it defined?

Comment: @Jawap Why do you not add a constructor  `Edge()` in `Edge` class to initialise a edge to zero. constructor overload!

Comment: @larsmans The edge between the node and its parent node. It stores properties about the edge such as length, name.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan How do I initialize it to zero? Do I have to add a member variable isZero and set it to true?

Comment: @Jawap : Add one more constructor in your `Edge` class.  `Edge(){ this->length=0; this->width=0; }` But better solution given by @sampson-chen. And the concept called default initialisation of function parameter.

Comment: Caution! I above comment I am assuming `length` and `width` are data members of `Edge class`.

Comment: Also according to OOP concepts if there required many changes(extensions) in `Edge` class then better it to create a subclass of `Edge` that is called `inheritance`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For appropriate use of member pointer vs. member variable, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175646/c-when-should-i-use-a-pointer-member-in-a-class).

Now, here is what you can do with the `Edge` class with regard to the "zero" value:

Change the constructor of `Edge` to read:

```
Edge(int length=0, int width=0)
```

This way when `Edge` is default constructed with `Edge e1` (or implicitly with `Node n1`), that constructor will be matched and the default values as specified will be used.

I'd say an edge of length 0 and width 0 makes perfect sense as a "zero" edge.

I've only listed one way to define default values for the constructor. There is [additional discussion on the topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187640/default-parameters-with-c-constructors).

Answer (score 1):

When the "custom creator" method (correctly termed the "constructor") for the `Node` class runs, any members of `Node` which are themselves objects (i.e. not basic types like ints, floats, chars, and not pointers) will have their own constructors run.

So the initial value of the `edge` object will be determined by what the constructor of the `Edge` class does. If the `Edge` class constructor requires arguments, then the `Node` constructor will have to provide them.

Suppose, for example, that the `Edge` constructor requires an integer called `weight`, e.g.:

```
class Edge {
  public:
    Edge(int w)
      : weight(w) {
    }

  private:
    int weight;
};
```

Then there are two options for giving a default weight to this edge. You can give the edge constructor have a default value for this parameter:

```
class Edge {
  public:
    Edge(int w = 0)
      : weight(w) {
    }

  private:
    int weight;
};
```

In which case the `Node` class does not need to do anything special. Or, you can have the `Node` class provide the parameter, e.g.:

```
class Node {
  public:
    Node()
      : edge(0),
        parent(NULL) {
    }

    Data data;
    Edge edge;
    Node *parent;
};
```