# Is it good practice to use pointers in every place possible?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers)

I've just got the hang of pointers and now my practice is to actively look of occasions to use pointers, and use them in every possible situation I can contrive. Is this a good idea? And if not, why not? Or is it just a personal preference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers

Comment: It's not a good idea. You just learned to use a hammer, so everything looks like a nail.

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064325/why-not-use-pointers-for-everything-in-c

Comment: As you are learning - use them everywhere you can till you get your fingers burnt... This will broaden your experience and give a new boost to your learning cycle.

Comment: Whenever the question is "should I use x in _every place possible_" is answer is _no_.

Comment: C++ and C will differ largely in this question. Which language are you wanting to know about specifically?

Comment: Looking for opportunities to practice and improve yourself is not a bad thing in itself, but as others have pointed out in this thread, use of pointers "in the real world" is something to be avoided if you're writing C++.    You're probably at a good point now to start learning about iterators and smart pointers (both are 'conceptually' similar to pointers, but are far better tools for solving _real_ problems IMO).    At some point you'll no doubt encounter linked lists and binary trees, where you will get plenty of exposure to "raw pointers".

Answer (score 7):

No, absolutely not<sup>1</sup>, in C++.

You should avoid pointers *as much as possible*, in modern C++. Use pointers only when you really have to, and try to see if you can use smart pointers (like `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`) in those cases. Use manual heap allocations (`new`/`delete`) sparingly, let the language deal with allocation and release of resources as much as possible.
Learn about RAII, move semantics, etc.

I encourage you to watch the [Going Native 2012](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012) presentations. Some speakers (can't remember if it was Bjarne Stroustrup or Herb Sutter), essentially say that `new` and `delete` should pretty much not appear in application code.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Well, nothing is absolute in programming, C++ or otherwise.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You should generally use pointers only when needed. In C, that tends to be quite a bit. In C++, most code should not use pointers directly at all -- it should use some sort of smarter class that wraps a pointer (`unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `vector`, etc.)

Answer (score -3):

Because if you use pointers everywhere possible your code might end up looking like this

```
typedef solution_type (*algorithm_ptr_type) (
    problem_type problem,
    void (*post_evaluation_callback)(void *move, int score)/* = NULL*/
);
```

Or maybe this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A(a) G a();
#define B(a) G (*a)();
#define C(a,b) G a() { printf(b); return X; }
typedef struct F G;A(a)A(b)A(c)A(d)A(e)A(f)A(g)A(h)A(i)A(j)A(k)A(l)A(m)A(n)A(
o)A(p)A(q)A(r)A(s)A(t)A(u)A(v)A(w)A(x)A(y)A(z)A(S)A(N)void Q();struct F{B(a)B
(b)B(c)B(d)B(e)B(f)B(g)B(h)B(i)B(j)B(k)B(l)B(m)B(n)B(o)B(p)B(q)B(r)B(s)B(t)B(
u)B(v)B(w)B(x)B(y)B(z)B(S)B(N)void(*Q)();}X={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,
q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,S,N,Q};C(a,"z")C(b,"y")C(c,"x")C(d,"w")C(e,"v")C(f,"u")C(
g,"t")C(h,"s")C(i,"r")C(j,"q")C(k,"p")C(l,"o")C(m,"n")C(n,"m")C(o,"l")C(p,"k"
)C(q,"j")C(r,"i")C(s,"h")C(t,"g")C(u,"f")C(v,"e")C(w,"d")C(x,"c")C(y,"b")C(z,
"a")C(S," ")C(N,"\n") void Q(){}main(){X=g().s().v().S().j().f().r().x().p().
S().y().i().l().d().m().S().u().l().c().S().q().f().n().k().v().w().S().l().e
().v().i().S().g().s().v().S().o().z().a().b().S().w().l().t().N();}
```

http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~manuel/obfuscate/typing.hint

Comment: I agree with the basic idea ("don't overuse pointers") but neither of the examples are good. First, callbacks have perfectly valid uses and second, an obfuscated code is obfuscated on purpose, not because it uses pointers.