# Owning instance of object vs owning pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's say I have two class A and B. There are 2 ways in which class B can use A.

First:

```
class B
{
  A *a;
}
```

Second:

```
class B
{
  A a;
}
```

Why most of the C++ libraries prefer to use `First` version as compared to `Second`. What could be the disadvantage of using Second approach. Does it relate to Stack vs Heap assignment? Please clarify.

Comment: I am not sure why you think the first version is better, I usually use the second. the first one, you should be carefull with class allocation, and deletion,

Comment: it depends on how you define `use`?

Comment: "Why most of the C++ libraries prefer to use First version as compared to Second" So you looked into > 50% of all existing C++ libraries? Joking apart, they're different. E.g. [Why not use pointers for everything?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1064325/420683) and many many other answers.

Comment: It depends on how A will be used. For example, if you had a getter function on B for A that returned a pointer to it: `A* a = b->getA();` and then b gets deleted, then in the second example, you'd have a dangling pointer `*a`

Comment: You could also store a reference to the instance of class A.

Comment: Five comments and no one has complained yet that [a raw pointer `A*` shouldn't be an owning pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/417635/420683)? I'm baffled ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some advantages of owning an instance (`class B { A a; };`):

- No need to worry about creation and destruction of `a` because it happens automatically.
- No need to worry that `a` might be a dangling or null pointer.
- Memory locality: `a` lives where instances of `B` live. If you have a large array of `B`s and access each `B`'s `A` in turn, this could make a significant speed difference.
- Memory efficiency: no storage for a pointer is needed.

To make a huge sweeping generalization, one could say that this approach is **faster** and **safer**.

Some advantages of owning a pointer (`class B { A *a; };)`:

- Polymorphism: `a` can actually point to a subclass of `A`.
- `a` can be reassigned without needing to copy an instance of `A`.
- `a` can live independently of `B` or even be owned by another object entirely.
- `a` can be null, freeing up memory if it's not always needed.

To make another huge sweeping generalization, one could say that this approach is **more flexible**.

Comment: Polymorphism can also be achieved using a reference. All of the advantages of the "pointer" category plus some of the "non-pointer" category can be achieved using a smart pointer.