# Difference in creating an object in C++ using new keyword and not

Tags: c++, new-operator

I'm new to `C++` I just want to know the difference between this statements:

**Note: Enemy is base class of Ninja class**

```
Ninja n;
Enemy * enemy = &n;
```

and

```
Enemy * enemy = new Ninja;
```

I also want to know when I should use any of those statements in case that they have difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064325/why-not-use-pointers-for-everything-in-c/1064388#1064388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Ninja n;
```

you allocate the Ninja on the stack and this

```
Enemy * enemy = &n;
```

gets a pointer to that location. Once you leave the current function, the memory in the stack is reused and your Ninja* will be *dangling*: if you try to access it (dereference) your program will crash or worse.

When you do this:

```
Enemy * enemy = new Ninja;
```

you allocate a new Ninja object on the heap. You can continue yo use your Ninja instance until you free the memory with

```
delete enemy;
```

Check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655065/when-should-i-use-the-new-keyword-in-c) to get a better idea of stack vs heap allocation.

Comment: *"Once you leave the current function"* is not really accurate - scope is the important thing here, not functions. *"Your program will crash or worse"* is also inaccurate - it may in fact continue to run just fine. What you will have is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Correct on both accounts. I chose simplicity over technical detail for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Ninja n;`  ----> n is in stack.You needn't destory it manually.

`new Ninja;`----> n is in heap. you should delete it with `delete enemy;` when you needn't it

**Notice**: when using the pointer of father class to delete the object of child class. You'd better define a virtual destructor function in both of classs.

Answer (score 0):

The new () will create an instance dynamically in memory ( like malloc () in C )
the first declaration has a statically allocated memory for the instance ( or allocated in teh stack if the declaration is inside a function ).

with new (), you will have to destroy the instance once it is no longer needed through the delete () method.

Comment: Sort of like `malloc`, but it calls the constructor after allocating the memory.