# Why return a pointer to a variable on the heap instead of the variable itself in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

So I'm coming from Java and am now learning C++,

I understand how pointers work, what the stack and heap memory are and I have googled a lot but i can not seem to understand why we wouldn't just return the object itself instead of a pointer pointing to a object created on the heap like in this example:

(I understand why we have to allocate the object on the heap and not on the stack in the first example.)

```
class Thingy;

Thingy* foo() 
{
  Thingy *pointerToHeap = new Thingy();
  return pointerToHeap;
}
```

So coming from Java i would have done it like this:

```
class Thingy;

Thingy foo()
{
  Thingy a;
  return a;
}
```

As I almost always got the reason that object on the heap live longer than objects on the stack I don't see why we would write a function like the first example if my function would work as well.

Comment: If the variable is too big to fit on the stack you don't have a choice (for example when you need a really big array of something)

Comment: It is legitimate to return the value, but not always advisable to do so.

Comment: So what would be better programming practice then, and when is it not advisable to just return the value?

Comment: Also, in case there's transfer-of-ownership involved, it's advisable to return a `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer. That change btw. does not break (for just about any) ABI, only API.

Comment: Well, in Java would it not be `Thingy a = new Thingy;` and you just don't have the `*`?

Comment: Seems to me the two are equal except for some syntax differences.

Comment: @crashmstr: Sure, but only because you always have 1-level-pointers in Java, never the object itself.

Comment: @JonathanWood: If you ignore that the Java example returns `null`, while the C++ one returns the address of an actual object, sure.

Comment: @Deduplicator My point is that the "So coming from Java i would have done it like this" example is wrong, since you would use `new` and you don't have the option of a stack based object.

Comment: So when should i use one over the other?

Comment: It depends on how the object will be used.  I would think in most cases the Java way you cited is the preferred way of doing it in C++.  A reason to keep the object on the heap and only pass a pointer might be as someone else stated, you are stack size limited.  Another reason might be you can only have 1 obect defined.  Another reason might be if you need to write a copy constructor but can't do it correctly.

Comment: @Styxs `So I'm coming from Java and am now learning C++,`  I know others have commented, but in general *Do not use Java as a model in writing C++ code*.  Otherwise, you'll just get yourself tied up in knots creating "strange looking" C++ code, if not faulty code altogether.  Pretend that Java never existed, and you're learning a new language.  Yes, you can pluck out an algorithm or algorithm-like code from a Java app and convert it to C++, but that would be the extent of it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah it's what i'm trying to do by asking myself stuff like my question above

Comment: If you fixed your Java example, then both cases would be returning pointers to *objects* (not variables) on the heap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your two examples are **not equivalent**:

In the Java example, you forgot to actually create an object.
Corrected code:

```java
class Thingy;

Thingy foo() {
    Thingy a = new Thingy();
    return a;
}
```

Syntax for Java pointers and C++ pointers are different, because Java does not allow stack-allocation, only heap-allocation, and no allocation of non-class-types. Which means there's no need to differentiate between single-level-pointers, multi-level-pointers and non-pointer variables, as all are single-level pointers.

There's an additional semantic difference between them:
While C++ *does* support garbage-collection, it's extremely rare, while in Java it's mandatory.

Thus, in C++, there are two better options:

1. Return by-value, if copying or moving is cheap:

   ```
   class Thingy;
   Thingy foo() {
       Thingy t; // Thingy t(); would declare a function instead.
       return t; // The copy/move will probably be elided due to NRVO
   }
   ```
2. Return using a `std::unique_ptr`, to explicitly denote transfer-of-ownership and make it exception-safe:

   ```
   #include <memory>
   class Thingy;
   std::unique_ptr<Thingy> foo() {
       unique_ptr<Thingy> p = new Thingy();
       return p;
   }
   ```

   This option also has the advantage of not breaking the ABI, for just about all platforms, if changing from your version.
   It breaks the API though, but that's easily corrected.

   - An alternative is returning a `std::shared_ptr`, to allow using `make_shared`:

     ```
     #include <memory>
     class Thingy;
     std::shared_ptr<Thingy> foo() {
         auto p = std::make_shared<Thingy>();
         return p;
     }
     ```

Comment: `Thingy t();` This isn't the most vexing parse here?

Comment: I tried not writing this:
    `Thingy a = new Thingy();`
because that would just create the object on the heap again, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Styxs: In Java, it would. In C++, it would create an object on the heap, and then try to construct another object on the stack given a pointer to the first one. Which will likely fail to compile, because there are few classes having reason to accept a pointer to an object of its type in the constructor.

Comment: @Deduplicator: So should i create the object on the heap now or on the stack when I want to return it like I did?
And if i would want to save perfomance I should return a pointer to the object on the heap, is that correct? (disregarding `std::unique_ptr`)

Comment: @Styxs I'm not sure whether your class is copyable/movable, and at what cost. Also, I don't know whether you ave other reasons to return a pointer. In general, try to stay away from pointers though. And if you have to use pointers, stay far away from owning raw pointers, as there are better-suited smart-pointers.

Comment: @Styxs Return an object as your general rule; if you have to return a pointer (fewer cases), prefer a smart one. And do not return a pointer to a local object.

Comment: @black Allright, thanks so i will be returning objects as my general rule, and use smart pointers when i have to.
I have read about when it would be good to use pointers, but i don't seem to understand why as i could just use objects again.
Would it be allright to just stick to objects and find out when pointers are useful as I am practicing C++?

Comment: @Styxs Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064325/why-not-use-pointers-for-everything-in-c?rq=1) question. BTW, you'll notice that you have to use pointers in some case like dynamic polymorphic objects. The less you use pointers, the better imho.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer example returns a pointer to the object. It is allocated on the heap and the caller can access the same copy directly. The caller also is responsible for deleting the Thingy from the heap at some point.

The object instance example constructs a Thingy on the stack and then that is copied to the caller's Thingy, assuming you have a line Thingy2 = Thingy1.foo() invoking the function. Depending on the size of the object there is a performance penalty compared to using one object.

Using std::shared_ptr would probably work more like the Java you are used to. It would create one copy of the object and dispose of it when it is no longer referenced. You could pass it around and every reference would be to the same copy of the object.